# Parallel arrows in tikzcd natural transformation

Tags: tikz-cd

I want to put two parallel arrows (`Rightarrow`) in a `tikz-cd` diagram but the node is too far away from the arrows when I shorten them.

```
\documentclass[utf8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
             H \dar[r,Rightarrow,shorten >= 10pt,shift left=1ex] \dar[r,Rightarrow,shorten >= 10pt,shift right=1ex] & F
             \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Any tips for improving this? t

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full minimal example taht we can copy and test as is without having to gess preamble and document class. Plus the code you provide is not even complete.

Comment: Sorry my fault. I hope it's ok now.

Comment: Why do you shorten them? `\dar` is wrong here. This is a down arrow which you tell to go to the right then... Just do `\ar[r]` or `\arrow{r}` or variants of that.

Comment: Don't use `\dar`, but `\arrow`; remove the `shorten` key; if you want that the nodes are nearer to each other, change `column sep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't shorten the arrows, but rather modify the column distance:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
H \arrow[r,Rightarrow,shift left=1ex] \arrow[r,Rightarrow,shift right=1ex] & F
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
H \arrow[r,Rightarrow,shift left=1ex] \arrow[r,Rightarrow,shift right=1ex] & F
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about this. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Just as addition to Mr. Gregorio, there is a third version for single columns:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    H \arrow[Rightarrow,shift left=1ex]{r} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift right=1ex]{r} & F \arrow[Rightarrow,shift left=1ex]{r} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift right=1ex]{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] % or column sep=0.5em or alike
    H \arrow[Rightarrow,shift left=1ex]{r} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift right=1ex]{r} & F \arrow[Rightarrow,shift left=1ex]{r} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift right=1ex]{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
    H \arrow[Rightarrow,shift left=1ex]{r} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift right=1ex]{r} &[-1em] F \arrow[Rightarrow,shift left=1ex]{r} \arrow[Rightarrow, shift right=1ex]{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]